# reset time zone offset android

Tags: android, date, utc

I have a date like

**datewithGMT** >>

```
Tue Oct 28 07:06:54 GMT+02:00 2014
```

and I want to reset it to

```
Tue Oct 28 07:06:54 2014
```

Using the following

```
   SimpleDateFormat df =    new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
   df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

    Date airDate = null;
    try {  
        airDate = df.parse(datewithGMT);   
    } catch (ParseException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

I again get the date with +2 GMT how can this offset be removed

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? In your example it looks like you just took off "2014" from the end.

Comment: Use SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern does not correspond to the input string. You need to change your `df` to `SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");`

You also need a second SimpleDateFormat. The completed implementation is below:

```
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM HH:mm:ss yyyy");
        df2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

        String datewithGMT = "Tue Oct 28 07:06:54 GMT+02:00 2014";

        Date airDate = null;
        try {  
            airDate = df.parse(datewithGMT);   
            Log.v(df2.format(airDate)); //it will print Tue Oct 28 07:06:54 2014
        } catch (ParseException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
```